# newly installed HDD not found in Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

In a brand new laptop with Ubuntu with 2 x 500MB SSD IDE, I have installed an extra HDD.
Ubuntu doesn't find it!

My son asked this question for me a couple of weeks ago and received the following response

you don't see any drives when you do dmesg | grep '/dev/sd' ? – NiteRain May 11 at 21:03
I think you can also do: sudo blkid – NiteRain May 11 at 21:04

Unfortunately, as this reply assumes a very highlevel of experience with Ubuntu, it is, to me, completely unintelligible. Requests for clarification have not met with any response.

Comment: Maybe the disk didn't connect correctly or it doesn't work. If the disk can be pluged in while the system is running, you can try to take the disk out, restart the laptop, check `dmesg` just to know what the last lines looks like. Then plug the disk in, maybe you can see it light up a led or hear it hum. *Check the last lines of ? dmesg?  again, hopefully there are some disk related information last.

Comment: Once again a totally useless "answer" becuase it assumes considerable experience with Linux whereas this is my first Linux computer which I am trying to get working.   What on Earth does dmesg mean???????????????   Or  ?dmesg?      An unintelligible "solution" is no solution if you don't tell me how to apply it.

Comment: you wont get much help here with that attitude.  We are all volunteers here, doing our best. If you don't understand a comment or answer, try to search this site, google it, or ask for clarification. Don't be rude, because then you will probably just get ignored, or your question gets closed for lack of effort.

Comment: `dmesg` is a command you run in a terminal. A terminal is opened by pressing CTRL-ALT-T and you close the terminal by pressing CTRL-d or writing exit and pressing Enter.